# How change the page on page init or load events depends on mobile device (iPhone)?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net C# website. Because of iPhone doesn't support flash i want to change a theme of my site on page load or init if user using it. Could any one show me (code in c#) how to determine that user is browsing my website using iPhone or iPad, not a blackberry, or android etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest [Module Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/), put it in your App_Browsers folder.

Then, in your `Page_Init`, check whatever [capabilities](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Capabilities&referringTitle=Home) you need (i.e. Flash):

```
if (Request.Browser["SupportedFlashVersion"] == "none") {
    // Change skin/theme/master page
}
```